# ExtJS4 File upload - How the get my file content not just the location

Tags: c#, file-upload, extjs, extjs4

I know how to create a form that browses and selects a file, that's not my question. What I need is to get the content of the selected file, to send it to a server and proccess it. For now I only can get the file location.

I think it will be better if I get my file on client side (extjs), then send it to server, but I have no idea how to do this.

```
{
    xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
    hideLabel: true,
    emptyText: 'Select a file to upload...',
    id: 'upfile',
    //name:'file',
    width: 220
},
buttons:
[
    {
        text: 'Upload',
        handler: function () {
            obj.Import(Ext.getCmp('upfile').getValue())
        }
    }
]
```

`Import(...)` is my server function. I need to give it the file not only its path!!

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: Import is my server function?? how is your server side code in ExtJS code?

Comment: it contains code to proccess the file , but i first need to give it the file which i dont know how to do !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing `Ext.getCmp('upfile').getValue()` is clearly passing the file location to Import method. How do you expect the file content then? In order to upload a file, you need to submit a ExtJS form. You can do something like this:

```
handler: function() {

        form.submit({
                url: '/Gallery/Upload',
                waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
                success: function(form, action) {
                    alert('File form done!');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And on server side:

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpPostedFile fileupload = context.Request.Files["file"];

    // process your fileupload...

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Ok");
}
```

**Update:** You need to uncomment the name property of your `fileuploadfield`.

Comment: thx..what is AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post) ? my .ashx does not recognise it

Comment: The code I posted was from MVC controller.. check the updated code

Comment: it works for me,thanks a lot, but i want to display message errors so i return a string,the problem is that when i use context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write(mymessage); it always trigguer the success method in extjs, when i don use it i dnt get any message:(

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK Ext doesn't use HTML5 File API, so getting file content on JS side isn't straightforward. Probably simplest way to achieve that is to create custom handler. Eg:

```
{
    xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
    hideLabel: true,
    emptyText: 'Select a file to upload...',
    id: 'upfile',
    //name:'file',
    width: 220
},
buttons:
[
    {
        text: 'Upload',
        handler: function () {
            var file = Ext.getCmp('upfile').getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0]; // fibasic is fileuploadfield
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    obj.Import(e.target.result);
                };
            })(file);
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: thx..im trying it, what is f in reader.readAsBinaryString(f); ? u mean file?

Comment: @astrocybernaute Yep, my bad. BTW [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) is nice tutorial about HTML 5 file API

Comment: another question plz..what is the type of e.target.result ? (to declare it in the import function) ty

Comment: It's binary string, which means it's plain string, but every character is single byte. In C# argument type should be string. Then you can convert it to byte array by calling `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value)`. Note that if you pass UTF8 coded file, it will have each multi-byte character splited into bytes. If you want to work with text files there is also `readAsText` method.

Comment: This helped me a lot. can i able to read .xls file with this?

Comment: You're able, but xls it's usually binary (zipped xml's), so playing with it (reading data for example) will be hard.